# Rails 4: Syntax for testing partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm trying to figure out Rails syntax for testing views & partials.

What is the difference between these two tests? Both succeed using my partial in app/views/layouts/_auth.html.erb.

```
assert_template layout: "layouts/application", partial: "_auth"
```

and this:

```
assert_template layout: "layouts/_auth"
```

Also here are the tests I have written out for this controller. All assertions pass, but I think I'm missing some conventions. If you see any please let me know.

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_template :index
    assert_template layout: "layouts/application"
    assert_template layout: "layouts/application", partial: "_auth"
    assert_template partial: "sessions/_sign_in_form" # Can the below partials be rewritten?
    assert_template partial: "shared/_user_error_messages"
    assert_template partial: "users/_user_form"
    assert_template partial: "layouts/_log_in_modal"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assertion tests that both layout "layouts/application" and partial "_auth" were rendered.

Second only checks for "_auth". 

Replace it with :partial since it would better communicate what "_auth" is.

You can refer to [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html)